# AngularJS: Force loss of focus

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to force everything on the page to lose focus at a certain point when the user is editing some items.

I found this solution apparently works using jquery - `$(':focus').blur()`

Is there a way i can do something similar using angular?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Along the lines of

```
var activeElement = document.activeElement;

if (activeElement) {
   activeElement.blur();
}
```

This is not really angular, it's pure DOM and javascript.

Comment: Thanks. Javascript is fine. It was more just avoiding having to use JQuery

Comment: $document[0].activeElement is the angulared version.